# How to wait until stream async is executed in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Hi I have async nodejs function where I am using stream concept. I want once stream is completed then I want to return from this function.

```
const removeMapping = async function (query) {

    let stream = query.foreach();
    stream.on('data', function (record) {
       client.delete(record);
    })
    stream.on('error', function (error) {

    })
    stream.on('end', function () {
        console.log("completed");
    })
};
```

I am calling this function like this but after execution of this line, stream async code after this.

```
await mapping.deleteMapping(cookie);
```

Does anyone know how to handle this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function doesn't need to be async as you are not calling await within the function.

What you can do is return a new promise:

```
const removeMapping = function (query) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let stream = query.foreach();
        stream.on('data', function (record) {
            client.delete(record);
        })
        stream.on('error', function (error) {
            reject(error);
        })
        stream.on('end', function () {
           resolve("completed");
        })

    })

};
```

You can then resolve or reject depending on what comes back from your stream.

Comment: You are resolving multiple times because I assume on data will be executed more than one, how do you handle that?

Comment: Then don't put a resolve in your on data listener. Just have the resolve in on end. What do you want to do when you receive data? (Updated answer to reflect this)